# Conversion failed when the nvarchar value 'Trading' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns. When I try this query, I get an error

> Conversion failed when the nvarchar value 'Trading' to data type int

But the values are numbers and `Trading` is not found in the `Test2` column.

Please help...

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE CoID IN ('', '1') 
  AND ID = 'Test2' 
ORDER BY CAST(Value AS int)
```

| CoID(nvarchar) | ID(nvarchar) | Value(nvarchar) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Test1 | Trading |
| 1 | Test2 | 10 |
| 1 | Test2 | 20 |
|  | Test3 | ABC |

Comment: use try_convert(int,Value)        try_convert() or try_cast() will return a NULL if the conversion fails.   Much better than throwing an error.

Comment: The first row has `Trading` in the `Value` column - and you using `ORDER BY CAST(Value AS INT)` ----> that's where your conversion error occurs. If the `Value` column is of type `nvarchar` - you should **NOT** use `CAST(Value AS INT)` in the `ORDER BY` clause ....

Comment: `CAST(Value AS int)` is using the `Value` column and trying to `CAST` it as `int`. "Trading" is in the first row of your sample data for the `Value` column. You also have `ABC` in the same `Value` column, which will cause the same error. What part of that is unclear? You can't `CAST` the NVarChar values `"Trading"` or `"ABC"` to `INT`.

Comment: @marc_s, I used ID = "test2" in where clause. "Trading" is for ID "test1". The issue does not happen in my local. It happens only on server. If I run this query on server, the issue does not happen. SELECT * FROM (SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE CoID IN ('', '1') 
  AND ID = 'Test2' ) TBL
ORDER BY CAST(TBL.Value AS int)

Comment: The short answer is that someone (you?) has attempted to store a pile of garbage in a table where everything is a string. Now you are trying to extract useful information from this pile but you do so by making assumptions that are not valid. When everything is stored as a string and you store random values throughout, you make query-writing that much more difficult by having to logically "avoid" conversion errors. If you can, go back and re-evaluate the decisions that led to this schema. Your current schema will be a continuous source of errors and problems.

Answer (score 0):

As TSQL is a declarative language, you cannot tell the query engine, how to retrieve the rows. You are getting conversion error due to short circuiting behavior on expressions.

You can avoid error by using CASE expressions.

[Read detailed post on short circuiting](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-t-sql-expression-short-circuiting)

```sql
create table TESTShortcircuit (colid nvarchar(30), id nvarchar(30), value nvarchar(30))
insert into TESTShortcircuit
values
('0','Test1',   'Trading'),
('1','Test2',   '10'),
('1','Test2',   '20'),
('','Test3','ABC');

SELECT * 
FROM testShortcircuit 
WHERE ColID IN ('', '1') 
  AND ID = 'Test2' 
ORDER BY (case when try_cast(id as int) is not null then cast(id as int) else null end)
```

| colid | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test2 | 10 |
| 1 | Test2 | 20 |

Comment: This issue does not happen in my local, just happen on server. Is it related to SQL server patch/version?

Comment: @Jackson, it is not guaranteed to work in your local also. It depends on the way the execution engine chooses to execute. it is better to go with CASE expression based logic to ensure that short circuit does not happen.

Comment: ISNUMERIC is not a good function to use for this purpose. TRY_CONVERT is far better.

Comment: It's now a rather confusing read because it says "You can avoid error by using CASE expressions." - and then shows a solution that contains zero `CASE` expressions.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you are right. sorry. updated my answer. case expression is the only way to avoid this short circuiting.